# How do I delete keyframes?

Tags: modeling, animation, keyframes

How do I delete frames that have been place by the auto key frame insertion tool thingy?

Comment: Go to the keyframe, and with your cursor in the viewport, press `Alt`+`I`

Comment: Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Opening up a **dope sheet** window allows you to view all keyframes that you've made, accidentally or otherwise. You can hit <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all the keyframes while hovering over the dope sheet; all frames are automatically selected. Hit <kbd>B</kbd> to select the frames in question and then delete them.